# Calculate the image of a function with a parameter

Tags: analysis

The function is ${1+m*x^2\over 1+x^4}$ and the "m" is the parameter. I have tried to differentiate, and it isn't difficult to know the value of the critical points, but the points are $-\sqrt{{\sqrt{1+m^2}-1\over m}}$ ; $\sqrt{{\sqrt{1+m^2}-1\over m}}$; and $0$, so I don't know what values choose to analyse the rise and decrease of the function.

Comment: What you say "image", do you mean "graph"? Or do you mean the set of points attained by the function?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ is increasing where $f'>0$ and decreasing where $f'<0$. You have to work with these inequalities.